# Hash tables Ω(n^2) runtime?

Tags: big-o, hashtable, theory

I am really confused about this. Having read the textbook and done exercises I still don't get how it works, and unfortunately I can't go in person to see the professor and it's somewhat difficult to get in touch (summer online course, different time zones). I feel like it would 'click' if I just understood how to do this problem. The textbook details hash functions and runtime individually but I feel like this question is outside the scope of what we've learned. If someone could point me at anything that might help, that would be great.

1) Consider the process of inserting *m* keys into a hash table T[0..*m* − 1], where *m* is a prime, and we use open addressing. The hash function we use is h(*k*, *i*) = (*k* + *i*) mod *m*. Give an example of *m* keys *k1*, *k2* ... *km*, such that the following sequence of operations takes Ω(*n^2*) time:

insert(*k1*), insert(*k2*), ..., insert(*km*)

I understand that insert operations are supposed to take O(1) time or, in some cases, O(n). How exactly am I supposed to come up with keys that will turn that into Ω(n^2) time? I'm hoping to understand this and I feel like I'm missing some huge hint, because the textbook chapter seems simple, makes sense to me, and doesn't help with this at all. In the question it's stated that *m* is a prime, is this important? I'm just so lost, and Google for once fails me.

Comment: Did you mean Omega(m^2), instead of Omega(n^2)?

Comment: No, the problem definitely uses n.

Comment: Every descending (by one) sequence will do , for instance: `m,m-1,m-2,...,2,1,0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword here is **hash collision**:

In order for a hash function to work well, you need the values for a certain input to be well-distributed over all `m` possible values the entries are stored in. If the hash table has about as many entries as elements were inserted, you can expect every element to be stored at (or near) its hash value (meaning only small amounts of probing are necessary), making access, insertion and deletion a constant-time operation.

If you however find different input values for which the hash function maps to the same value every time (collisions), during insertion the probing step will have to skip over all previously added elements, taking Ω(n) time per element on average. Thus we get a runtime of Ω(n²)

Comment: Thanks. So for example 3, 9, and 27 would work since those all hash to 0 unless i is changed?

Comment: If your hash table has `m=3` entries, then yes, just like 6, 15, 24, ... How exactly you create the collisions depends on your hash function, but I think you got the concept.